# creating covered index for aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I have a problem with creating index for my query and can't find any similar solution on the web, so maybe some of you will help me.

To simplify problem let's say we have Phones with some attributes,

```
{
  "type":"Samsung",
  "model":"S3",
  "attributes":[{
     "value":"100",
     "name":"BatteryLife"
   },{
     "value":"200$",
     "name":"Price"
   }
}
```

With index: {"type":1, "attributes.value":1}

We have millions of phones for every type and i want to find phones for given type that have given attributes, my query looks like:

```
db.Phone.aggregate([ 
{ "$match" : { "type" : "Samsung"}} , 
{ "$match" : { "attributes" : { "$all" : [ 
    { "value" : "100", "name" : "BatteryLife" } , 
    { "value" : "200$", "name" : "Price"}
                              ]}
             }
 }
])
```

And it works !
The problem is that this query is highly inefficient, beacuse it use only first part of my index, that is "type"(and i have millions of phones of every type), and doesn't use 'attributes.value' part (type + attributes.value is almost unique, so it would reduce complexity significantly).

@Edit
Thanks to Neil Lunn i know it's because index is used only in my first match, so i have to change my query.

@Edit2
I think i found solution:

```
db.Phone.aggregate([
{$match: {
    $and: [ 
        {type: "Samsung"}, 
        {attributes: {
           $all: [
                { "value":"100", "type" : "BatteryLife" },
                { "value":"200$", "type" : "Price" }
           ] 
        }}
    ]}
}])
```

+db.Phone.ensureIndex({type:1, attributes:1}), seems to work. I think we can close now. Thanks for tip about $match.

Comment: For a covered index you need to have **all** fields used in the query to be included **and** in order. The main problem here is you are writing **multiple** match phases when all the conditions should be in **one** phase at the beginning only. After that first match, there is no more usage of the **index**. While there is a lot of information in your question, it does not describe the **problem** you are really trying to solve. That is the **best** format for questions here.

Comment: It would too long to explain my real problem, but the data structure is exactly the same. Thanks for tip that index is used only in first match, i somehow missed that.

Comment: Trying to point out to you that you haven't explained your problem at all. You're already flagged for close votes. The best way to avoid that is re-phrase your question into something people can solve.

Comment: I've edited my post, hope it's more clear now. I will try to rearrenge my query and put both "type" and "attribute.value" in one match if that's possible. please doesn't close this topic.

Comment: you should remove $and from the query - there is no need for it here, since the "," is already "and" equivalent.  In addition, your query syntax is likely not what you want.  Is suspect you intend to use $elemMatch to get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

To get the most out of the index you need to have a $match early enough in the pipeline that uses all the fields in the index.  And avoid using `$and` operator since it's unnecessary and in the current (2.4) version can cause an index not to be fully utilized (luckily fixed for the upcoming 2.6).

However, the query is not quite correct as you need to use `$elemMatch` to make sure the same element is used to satisfy the name and value fields.

Your query should be:

```
db.Phone.aggregate([
{$match: {  type: "Samsung", 
           attributes: { $all: [
                {$elemMatch: {"value":"100", "type" : "BatteryLife" }},
                {$elemMatch: {"value":"200$", "type" : "Price" }}
           ] }
        }
}]);
```

Now, it's *not* going to be a covered query, since the attributes.value and name are embedded, not to mention the fact that name is not in the index.

You need the index to be `{"type":1, "attributes.value":1, "attributes.name":1}` for best performance, though it still won't be covered, it'll be much more selective than now.