# aggregation complexity in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I have a query that groups the results (large dataset~= 11Gb) by a value (vessel_id) and returns for each vessel the coordinates in an array.

The query looks like this:

```
pipeline = [{"$group": {"_id": "$properties.vessel_id",
            "COORDINATES": {                                                                    
            "$push": "$geometry.coordinates"}}}]                                                        


getPositionsOfshipsgrouped = db.samplecol.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

The output is:

```
{u'_id': u'566679000', u'COORDINATES': [[154.666, -16.643], [154.666, -16.643], [154.666, -16.643]]}

{u'_id': u'636015725', u'COORDINATES': [[151.5162, -9.44365], [151.5162, -9.44365], [151.5162, -9.44365]]}

{u'_id': u'525018017', u'COORDINATES': [[117.3803, -1.029925], [117.3803, -1.029925], [117.3803, -1.029925]]}
```

In total the dataset contains 41000 vessel_id's. I observe that the time to fetch the output for all the vessels is almost equal with the time to fetch the output for 500 vessels.

For example the time to execute query with `$limit:500` is almost equal with the time to execute the query with `$limit:41000`:

```
pipeline = [{"$group": {"_id": "$properties.vessel_id",
                "COORDINATES": {                                                                    
                "$push": "$geometry.coordinates"}}},
                 {"$limit":500}]                                                        


getPositionsOfshipsgrouped = db.samplecol.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

**Time**: 720 sec

```
pipeline = [{"$group": {"_id": "$properties.vessel_id",
                "COORDINATES": {                                                                    
                "$push": "$geometry.coordinates"}}},
                 {"$limit":41000}]                                                        


getPositionsOfshipsgrouped = db.samplecol.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

**Time**: 780 sec

What I miss here? Is something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Neil Lunn, thank you rof the response. I am new in Mongo. So you tell me, to add the limit in fron of the query?

Comment: Read above. I have no idea what you think you are trying to do. You need to explain better. But everything happening right here is exactly what is supposed to happen since that is what you are asking it to do.

Comment: My question is why I observe the same time when I fetch the coordinates of all vessels and when I fetch the coordinates of 500 vessels. The query that I have may be wrong of course.

Comment: Read the first line again. All the "work" is being done in the `$group`. Changing the `$limit` on returned cursor results has no effect. That is how it's meant to work. Refresh this page as you may be reading only part of the detail.

Comment: @Antonis `$limit` has no effect on `$group` stage... you need to put `$limit` stage before `$group` stage

Comment: I try the solution with the $limit (500) before $group and the query returns 2 vessel id with the COORDINATES sum = 500. If  I want to return 500 vessels? Is there a way to limit the query by the vessel_id?

Comment: If you are asking **why** - it is because $group is a blocking stage. It process the whole 11GB collection, doesn't matter what next stages are. Think about stages in aggregation pipeline as piped `|` bash commands. If you are asking **how to improve** - you cannot. Using covered indexes as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091373/creating-covered-index-for-aggregation-framework could help, but requires deep understanding of what you are doing and where you can compromise to get slightly better timing.

Comment: Thank you @AlexBlex

Comment: @Antonis You can find distinct `vessel_id` using `distinct` query with `limit` and then you can apply `$group` in it.

Comment: can you add an example please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see the example

```
db.collection.distinct('vessel_id').limit(10000)

db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { vessel_id: vessel_id }},
  {"$group": {"_id": "$properties.vessel_id",
                "COORDINATES": {                                                                    
                "$push": "$geometry.coordinates"}}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a solution that costs and is not suitable in my case, but remains a solution.

Comment: @Antonis does this reduces the query time? or increases?

Comment: This db.collection.distinct('vessel_id').limit(10000) ithink that costs.

Comment: What's the point to do distinct 10000, if aggregation returns coordinates for single vessel_id?

Comment: @Antonis if this solution doesn't work for you then you can unmark it so seeing it unanswered the people will visit the page... you might get your answer...

Comment: @Antonis Did you have index on `vassel_id` field?